# Can't initialize UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

```
if (cell == nil) {

//cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 44) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

//The line above works like a breeze

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];   //This is the line that is causing me problems
}
```

These are the error logs:

```
/Users/myname/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTableView.m: In function '-[MyTableView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]':

/Users/myname/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTableView.m:88: error: 'initWithStyle' undeclared (first use in this function)

/Users/myname/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTableView.m:88: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

/Users/myname/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTableView.m:88: error: for each function it appears in.)

/Users/myname/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTableView.m:88: error: 'UITableViewCellStyleValue1' undeclared (first use in this function)

/Users/myname/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTableView.m:88: warning: no '-initWithStyle::reuseIdentifier:' method found

/Users/myname/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTableView.m:88: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature

/Users/myname/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTableView.m:88: warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept

/Users/myname/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTableView.m:88: warning: '...' as arguments.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you compiling for OS 3? I don't believe `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` existed in OS 2...

Comment: how do you check that? I believed I am compiling for OS 3

Comment: Check project info, General section "Base SDK for All Configurations": does it iPhone Device 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

The correct method is

```
initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
```

You are using instead

```
initWithStyle:initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
```

Simply delete the redundant initWithStyle: and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCellStyleValue1` was not defined in SDKs prior to 3.0.  Check the SDK you are using.